# Generating SSH public/private keys in windows without GUI

Tags: ssh

I need to create the SSH Key pairs in windows. I need to do it programatically, ie without using the puttygen.exe GUI. Kindly get me ways to accomplish the same.

-Bala

Comment: I'd look here: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-windows

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the best solution is to install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html) or Git for Windows if you might need Git at some point.

If Cygwin is installed, in the terminal it can be done the same way as on Linux.
[GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) provides a nice tutorial on generating SSH keys.

For the record:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

The keys by default are placed in `~/.ssh` which in Windows is `C:\Users\USER_NAME\.ssh\` or simply `%HOME%\.ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried puttygen.exe from command line ?
Manual with examples: http://linux.die.net/man/1/puttygen
Should work on windows too.

If this not help, I will look for windows version of 'ssh-keygen' http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen